# How make a list of cumulative sum in netlogo

Tags: simulation, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

How can i make a list of cumulative sum of a other list?

i tried it that way:

```
;;all temperatrue-values around the turtle saved in list 
set temperature_values (list [(output-heat + 1)^ Freedom] of neighbors) 


;;build cumulative value of temperatures and put each value in list 
let tempsum 0 
set tempsum_list [] 
foreach temperature_values 
[set tempsum (tempsum + ? ) 
set tempsum_list fput tempsum tempsum_list 

]
```

but it doesn't work. can anyone fix this problem? it says that "+ excepted a input but gets a list instead".

Comment: I am a bit unsure. Are you trying to make a list of sums? or just take the sum of a list?

Comment: is temperature-values a list of lists? type show  temperature-values into the observer input. What do you get.

Comment: temperature_values is a list with 8 values. it contains the values of "output-heat" of the neighbors. 

i want to make a list of cumulative sums of the list above. 

for example: list 1 [ 1 2 3 4 ] -> list 2 [1 3 6 10]

Answer (score 3):

your code for a cumulative sum works (except that I think you need `lput` rather than `fput`. You can see it with this:

```
to test
  let ll [1 2 3 4] 
  let tempsum 0 
  let tempsum_list [] 
  foreach ll 
  [ set tempsum (tempsum + ? ) 
    set tempsum_list lput tempsum tempsum_list 
  ]
  print tempsum_list
end
```

Did the error highlight the line `set temperature_values (list [(output-heat + 1)^ Freedom] of neighbors)`? Try putting a space after between ) and ^. NetLogo is picky about space around mathematical operators.

Comment: the error highlights: (tempsum + ?)
and says: "+ expected input to be a number but got the list [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1] instead.:

lput instead of fput is not working. it sends the same error

Answer (score 1):

As Jen suggested, you can use `foreach`.  Another nice approach is reduce:

```
to-report partial-sums [#lst]
  set #lst (fput [0] #lst)  ;;prepare for reduce
  report butfirst reduce [lput (?2 + last ?1) ?1] #lst
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Alan's solution (Just an update for the recent version of NetLogo that replaces ? with -> for anonymous procedures.)

```
to-report partial-sums [lst]
report butfirst reduce [[result-so-far next-item] -> lput (next-item + last 
result-so-far) result-so-far] fput [0] lst
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is like Alan's solution, just abstracted a bit further. (Perhaps too far, depending on your taste! I like JenB's solution as well.)

Let's first define a thing like `reduce`, but that keeps all the intermediate results:

```
to-report scan [fn xs]
  report reduce [lput (runresult fn ?2 last ?1) ?1]
                (fput (list first xs) butfirst xs)
end
```

Now we can use it to compute partial sums:

```
observer> show scan task + [1 2 3 4 5]
observer: [1 3 6 10 15]
```

but we are also free to swap in a different operation:

```
observer> show scan task * [1 2 3 4 5]
observer: [1 2 6 24 120]
```

Comment: yes this works. but i want to use it in the code and not in the observer window.

Comment: Eh? It doesn't matter, the same code will work in either place.