# How to plot a cumulative sum (running total) of a turtles-own variable in Netlogo?

Tags: simulation, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I can plot the sum of worms per animal using the code below (visualized in ***Figure 1***).

```
plot sum [worm-number] of animals
```

[image: Figure 1. Graph showing sum of worms per animal with a Netlogo Monitor]
***Figure 1.***

I want my graph to be cumulative however like ***Figure 2*** but I don't know how to code this. [Previous examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33570658/how-make-a-list-of-cumulative-sum-in-netlogo?noredirect=1&lq=1) use older syntax which does not work in NetLogo 6.2.0 and does not show how to plot the data.

[image: Figure 2. Example of a cumulative graph which is required (I only need to plot 1 variable).]
***Figure 2.***

Answer (score 3):

You only have to use a global variable which will keep track of the new worms, and to which you will refer for plotting.

As we do not have a full example of your code, I am just going to write something that plausibly mimics what you should do:

```
breed [animals animal]

globals [
 cumulative-worms
]

; **************************
; The rest of your code here
; **************************

to get-infected   ; The procedure executed by animals when they get new worms.
 let new-worms (1 + random 5)
 set worm-number (worm-number + new-worms)
 set cumulative-worms (cumulative-worms + new-worms)
end
```

At this point you can just create a plot where you will use `plot cumulative-worms`.